# Xamarin Group ListView Filtered By SearchBar

Tags: listview, xamarin, search, mvvm

I have a xamarin listview working with a search bar. It show everything or filters based on what you type. How can I get the listview to be grouped a well? I would like to group them by state. Members are pulling from a web service and I have a list of States. Thanks in advance.

ListView Xaml

```
                <ListView x:Name="ListViewMember"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding PublicMembersList}"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      HasUnevenRows="true"
                      RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadMembersCommand}"
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                      ItemSelected="OnMemberSelected"
                      SizeChanged="OnPageSizeChanged"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                      SeparatorColor="#000000">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PublicMembersList.Count, StringFormat='Active Members = {0}'}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ListView.Header>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ContentView>
                                <Frame>
                                    <StackLayout x:Name="GridMemberList" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <BoxView Color="PaleGreen" HeightRequest="25"></BoxView>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding pMember}"></Label>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </ContentView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

ListView Code Behind

```
        private void OnSearchChanged(object s, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        ListViewMember.BeginRefresh();

        ViewModel.SearchMembersCommand.Execute(null);

        ListViewMember.ItemsSource = ViewModel.FilteredGroupList;

        ListViewMember.EndRefresh();

    }
```

View Model dealing with the Model

```
    public class MemberViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public int PublicMemberCount => PublicMembersList.Count;

    public ObservableCollection<MemberModel> FilteredGroupList;

    private ObservableCollection<MemberModel> LocalMembersList;

    public ObservableCollection<MemberModel> PublicMembersList
    {
        get
        {
            return LocalMembersList;
        }

        set
        {
            LocalMembersList = value;
            SetProperty(ref LocalMembersList, value);
        }
    }

    private String LocalMemberString;

    public String PublicMemberString
    {
        get
        {
            return LocalMemberString;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref LocalMemberString, value);
        }
    }

    public Command LoadMembersCommand { get; set; }

    public Command SearchMembersCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() => ExecuteSearchMembersCommand());
        }
    }

    public MemberViewModel()
    {

        Title = "Member Lookup";

        PublicMembersList = new ObservableCollection<MemberModel>();

        LoadMembersCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadMembersCommand());

        if (PublicMembersList.Count == 0)
        {
            LoadMembersCommand.Execute(null);
        }

    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadMembersCommand()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {


            PublicMembersList.Clear();

            var m = await DataSource.GetMembersAsync(true); 

            var d = Services.DataList.GetStates();

            var l = new ObservableCollection<StateModel>(d); 



            foreach (var i in m)
            {

                PublicMembersList.Add(i);
            }

            FilteredGroupList = new ObservableCollection<MemberModel>();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Something - " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }

    }

    private void ExecuteSearchMembersCommand()
    {


        PublicMembersList.GroupBy(c => c.PhysicalState);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PublicMemberString))
        {

            FilteredGroupList = new ObservableCollection<MemberModel>();

        }
        else
        {

            IEnumerable<MemberModel> f = PublicMembersList.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(PublicMemberString));

            FilteredGroupList = new ObservableCollection<MemberModel>(f);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ListView grouping is covered in the official docs.  Have you read them?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping

Comment: Of course! Which is why I'm asking here. I'm getting data from my web service then filling the model dynamically as opposed to manually populating the lists like in the link you proved. Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a group class that inherits an IEnumerable. It only needs one property which is what you want the group name to be.

```
public class MemberModelGroup : ObservableCollection<MemberModel>
{
    public string Display{get;set;}
}
```

Change all lists to use `IEnumerable<MemberModelGroup>`. Then when you get your list of `MemberModels` from the server you need to place them into the correct `MemberModelGroup`. Each group is an element in UnfilteredList which is of type `IEnumerable<MemberModelGroup>` so you have a list of groups that you can filter using `MemberModelGroup.Display`.

```
var listOfMemberModels = FromServer.GetMemberModels();
foreach(var memberModel in listOfMemberModels)
{
    var group = UnfilteredList.FirstOrDefault(el => el.Display == memberModel.StateName);
    if(group == null)
    {
        var newGroup = new MemberModelGroup{ Display = memberModel.StateName };
        newGroup.Add(memberModel);
        UnfilteredList.Add(newGroup);
    }
    else
    {
        group.Add(memberModel);
    }
}
```

Last step is to enable grouping and specify the Binding to use.

`<ListView IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Display}">`

Comment: What should I do with the following then? I had to comment it out to avoid errors.    

IEnumerable<MemberModel> f = PublicMembersList.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(PublicMemberString));
FilteredGroupList = new ObservableCollection<MemberModel>(f);

Comment: FilteredGroupList is of object type ObservableCollection<MemberModelGroup>? You need to place each element of f in an appropriate MemberModelGroup. then FilteredGroupList to and ObservableCollection<MemberModelGroup>. I'll edit my answer to correct this

Comment: alright i've edited my answer to correct that. it doesn't have to be of type ObservableCollection, but i generally use that so it updates itself with changes. The gist is you want a list of groups that you feed to the ListView.

Comment: ahhhh gotcha. makes sense. it works perfect now. thank you.